# Video seeking does not work in PWA (Progressive Web App)

Tags: progressive-web-apps

html5 video player seeking does not work in PWA (Progressive Web App) as standalone APP.
Tested devices: Android and iOS.

When you accessing to the Web Page via Safari or Chrome it's working fine, but not as pwa standalone app.

What is the problem with that?

Comment: Is the app your own? Can you provide more details about it?

Comment: That is a PWA, I made it and everything works fine. But the only problem is with video player seeking. If I click play it plays. But if I seek to some point forward, its takes pretty long time to play from that place, depends how far its from the start point. So it looks kinda it loads too much slow, or something. The same website from mobile chrome browser works as a charm. Seeking is fast as a bullet. the only problem is within PWA.

Comment: Are you caching the video using the Cache Storage API and serving the cached response using a service worker?

Comment: I am caching the offline page with the service worker, but not the videos, since each of them is 300MB - 1.5GB .

Comment: I can't think of any reason why you're seeing what you describe if there is no service worker involvement. I'd recommend filing a bug at https://crbug.com/new (assuming you're seeing this with Chrome) with more details.

Answer (score 3):

This is due to a gap in the spec which was recently fixed. If you're interested in the details, [I wrote an article about it](https://jakearchibald.com/2018/i-discovered-a-browser-bug/#media-via-a-service-worker-didnt-quite-work).

Once browsers update to the new spec, media will just work as expected. Here are the related tickets:

- https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=847428
- https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1465074
- https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-edge/platform/issues/17689699/
- https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=186050

In the meantime, everything should work as expected if you use [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS):

```
<video crossorigin></video>
```

…although this requires the server to support CORS.

Comment: adding the crossorigin attribute to the video tag solved the problem for me.

Comment: @JaffaTheCake great article. Loved reading it. Is this issue fixed already? I am having problems in my PWA now, where service worker fails to feed the media player with video source.